# Solving the equation $|z^2-z+1|=|x^2-1|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, absolute-value

$z \in \mathbb{U}$, let $x= |z-1|$, show that :$|z^2-z+1|=|x^2-1|$

I tried from both sides but nothing worked for me, any ideas ?

Comment: What is $\Bbb U$?

Comment: that is to say $|z|=1$

Comment: So the complex unit circle?

Comment: yes, exactly  $\mathbb{U}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{T}$, we can also say that it is the complex unit circle

Comment: Have you tried squaring this equation, and then using the definition of absolute value squared?

Comment: Yes, but I may have been wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $x^2=(z-1)(\bar{z}-1)=z\bar{z}-z-\bar{z}+1$.  Since $\bar{z}=\dfrac{1}{z}$ for $z\in\mathbb{U}$, we get
$$x^2-1=\frac{z-z^2-1}{z}=-\frac{z^2-z+1}{z}\,.$$
That is,
$$\left|x^2-1\right|=\frac{\left|z^2-z+1\right|}{|z|}=\left|z^2-z+1\right|\,.$$

Comment: Arr, I didn't see it like that, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$z=x+iy$$ we get
$$|x^2-y^2+2xyi-x-iy+1|=|(x-1)^2+y^2-1|$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: thanks too, but my teacher doesn't like so much the "x and y" notation

Comment: Hm the other solution given here is not much better!

Comment: It remaines all the absolute values to solve!